# How to call PHP function on html button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I make a php function and when i click on add event button its add select box who populate events from database.

Here is my code:

```
<?
function addevents(){
$strQuery1="SELECT event_id,event_name from events";
$result1 = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($strQuery1) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
?>
<select id="thirdevent" name="thirdevent">
<?  
    while($ors1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo '<option value="'.$ors1['event_id'] .'" >' . $ors1['event_name'] . '</option>';
    } 
 }
?>
<input type="button" name="add" value="Add Event" onclick="addevents();"/>
```

Comment: you should use ajax call instead of php function for onclick event

Comment: You are confusing js and php. The php is only run on page load. As mentioned above, ajax is the way to go here

Comment: If you want an easy way to do an Ajax call use jquery (jquery.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using jquery ajax method,

PHP File "addEvents.php"

```
<?php

$strQuery1="SELECT event_id,event_name from events";
$result1 = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($strQuery1) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
echo '<select id="thirdevent" name="thirdevent">';
while($ors1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo '<option value="'.$ors1['event_id'] .'" >' . $ors1['event_name'] . '</option>';
    } 
echo '</select>';
?>
```

HTML and JS/Jquery/Ajax Part:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script>
function addevents()
{
$.post("addEvents.php",function(data){
$("#html_data").html(data);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="add" value="Add Event" onclick="addevents();"/>
<div id="html_data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will work as you wanted, i hope it will help..

Comment: when i used your code it gives me error TypeError: $.post is not a function

Comment: This means, you havn't properly attached jquery library in < head > tags. Make sure its attached! i.e. <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>

Comment: i attached but still same error

Comment: I copied same code in new html file and ran it, it ran perfectly! Can you post the code here of html, which you are trying?

Comment: <head>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();

function addevents()
{
$.post("form_add_events.php",function(data){
$("#html_data").html(data);
});
}
</script>
</head>

Comment: You haven't copied code!! if you did then you should not have missed "http://" before "code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ... kindly put http://

Answer (score 2):

PHP is server language and javascript is browser language,
For connect PHP & Js languages Just Use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Your Question is not useful

Read More books And Learn on the Web...

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a bit more detail from previous answers:

[PHP is a preprocessor](http://php.net) ([it's actually in its name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.general.php#faq.general.acronym)!). Essentially, everything in PHP is performed on the server, *before the page is even sent to the user*.

[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is executed *in your browser*. With this two points alone, PHP and JavaScript do not co-exist alongside each other at the same time, as they are executed at different points in a request.

**However**, it is possible to communicate between the two languages. There are several methods typically used to achieve this goal.

**PHP to JavaScript:** You may find yourself wanting to use server settings in your JavaScript. As a simple example, you may have a setting in your PHP which chooses what background color to turn a page after ten seconds. This can't be done without JavaScript, but the setting is in PHP. The solution is to use PHP/HTML to create JavaScript variables on your page to use.

E.g. **Above** your main JavaScript / JavaScript file, on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var server_settings = {
        'background_color' : '<?php echo $background_color; ?>'
    }
</script>
```

Then later on in your JavaScript:

```
if(server_settings.background_color) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = server_settings.background_color;
    }, 1000 * 10); // 10 seconds
}
```

**JavaScript to PHP:** Because PHP is server side, you use a bit of functionality known as AJAX to speak to your server. [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) stands for **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**, though the [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) part is commonly swapped out for [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Essentially, your JavaScript sends a request over to your server via. a URL. The page requested contains PHP, and any data sent via. JavaScript is picked up via the request headers. For example, a GET request to your AJAX url e.g. http://example.com/deletepost.php?id=5 will allow PHP to pick up data passed via. `$_GET` (in the example url provided, `deletepost.php` could use `$_GET['id']` to figure out what post you want to delete.

Other methods include [cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) and [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).

In your situation, you want the web page to perform a server side action after a client side action. This means you need to take the route of **JavaScript to PHP**. Because of this (which is why everyone else has said it), you should use AJAX.

E.g.

Bind an onClick event to a JavaScript function.

The function (when triggered) sends an AJAX request off to the server.

The server responds by outputting the data.

The JavaScript parses and displays the data to the user.

For further reading, I'd suggest you look into AJAX, and how to safely and effectively pass data to the server using it.